# How to kill all installed apps

Tags: android

I want to implement a button that kills all running apps and associated processes myself, but I cannot make it to work with some installed apps.

I tried

```
activityManager.restartPackage( packageName );

activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses( packageName ); (Which is the new version of restartPackage)

android.os.Process.killProcess( pid );
```

My issue is that some apps don't get killed and when a refresh the list of running apps, they still there.

I've read:

[ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)

[Android: Killing (all) Foreground running App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733311/android-killing-all-foreground-running-app)

Comment: Some men just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: BTW It will just kill the processes for that time. Many applications use STICKY services which revive themselves when killed. So maybe that's happening.

Comment: I'll have a look on that. Thanks.